# iphone - localized strings not working on device

Tags: iphone, localization

I tried everything I found on the web to fix this:

I have two «Localizable.strings» files - one in English, one in German. The app refuses to use the translations, though. It works on the simulator - but not on the device

I made a clean-build, removed the app from the device, even removed the localizable.strings, checked if the encoding is set to UTF-16... nothing helps...

Any ideas?

[Edit] In a last desperate attempt, it seems I fixed it. I had to restart the device after uninstalling the app - now it's working... Maybe this helps someone else...

Comment: You should Google your problems first. Check if also this one helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021978/ios-localization-localizable-strings-not-working

Comment: I did Google like crazy, Parth, and I found both of your links - both didn't help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the problem was another Localizable.strings file that was in my project. I added a framework to the project and some of the examples that came with it. One of them had its own Localizable.strings file - which then confused the compiler, it seems...