# iOS9 Added a new localization but it shows the last language used when selected

Tags: ios, localization

I seem to have an odd problem. I added a new language to my app, `Bahasa Indonesia`. I localised the story board files and the `.strings` files like I always do. Now when I select this language in iOS 10+ it works fine but if I use iOS9 it won't show the Indonesian language but instead shows the last used language. No idea what is going on here. Has anyone else had this type of problem before?

Comment: add related code.

Comment: Could you please provide details as if it is happening for Bahasa Indonesia language or if you select any language ,it display previous settings? 
I would suggest to check language using let language = NSBundle.mainBundle().preferredLocalizations.first as NSString
for iOS 9

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021978/ios-localization-localizable-strings-not-working